# Getting Controller / View to recognize different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise in Rails to help authenticate users. I am trying to create users within the system. I created a scaffold (just for the auto-generated code) Employee, and I changed the table in the employees_controller.rb to User. When I list the employees, it correctly lists the users. But when I attempt to add a new user, it gives me the error:

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x7fb289704bd8>:0x7fb289702540>
```

It gives me the error for the line:

```
<%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
```

What can I do to allow this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use scaffolding for your user model when implementing devise. However, if you use scaffolding, I would create that first and then follow [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns) tutorial for adding devise to that model.

Comment: I didn't use scaffolding to create the User model: I created that using rails generate devise User attribute1:string etc. I created the scaffold Employee, and changed the table reference inside of employee_controller.rb from Employee to User.

Comment: So why then name the controller employee, and not just have it as a user controller? I actually just tonight wrote something up similar in a blog post.

Comment: I'll attempt to do the same thing with a User controller, and I will definitely check out your blog!

Comment: I actually just thought about it more, and the actual answer to your question would be to add to your routes.rb: `resources :users, :controller => 'employee'`. My previous comment still won't work until you tell rails which controller to use for your model. Tired and my brain is not wanting to work tonight.